# Do I need an API Gateway

Tags: api, aws-api-gateway, ibm-api-management

I have an application that has a couple of features that I would like third parties business to avail of. for example the user information gets passed to us and we run ID checks and send back a token with information.

I think I can use a third party API management service like 3scale but what do I have to do on my end to 'expose' this API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With AWS API Gateway, you can [setup a simple http proxy to your application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-set-up-http-proxy-integration-on-proxy-resource). Based on your needs, you can use features like [auth](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html), throttling, API keys management, [client certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html) etc.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/api-gateway-update-new-features-simplify-api-development/) is a blog explaining some of this.

Hope this helps, Ritisha.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ritisha, API Gateway definitely can work, but it is sort of lock it.

I would recommend checking https://tyk.io/, which is an open source Gateway with commercial options. And for example it provides you Cloud version, where you do not need to expose any ports on your side at all. You just configure your API in dashboard and can just bind your CNAME record to the proxied API. This should work really well to try it out. And if you grow up this options, you can host it on your own, or use Hybrid environment, when all user requests come to your own server (no 3-rd parties), but on the other hand, have nice configuration dashboard in the cloud.

Hope it helps!